# Group actions on polytopes in indefinite integer lattices

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, discrete-geometry, lattices, combinatorial-geometry

Is anything at all known about polytopes in indefinite integer lattices? I'm interested in lattice automorphisms which preserve certain polytopes of "high regularity" (e.g. cones). As a first step, I'd like to be able to classify the polytopes with certain properties (perhaps we've specified part of the Gram matrix, for example). The lattices I'm working with are likely to be fairly close to Lorentzian (signature (1, n) or (2, n) ). Anything would be useful (including specific examples or special cases).

Thanks.

Comment: It would helpful if the question included a bit more background, and the question was more focused.

Comment: I'm trying to understand torsion in the orthogonal group of certain indefinite lattices. The polytopes would correspond to orbits of a base of the lattice.